Fedora gets stuck at boot logo spinner sometimes (not always)
I have a ThinkPad T480 running Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation). It works fine, but sometimes randomly during boot after entering disk encryption password the Lenovo and Fedora logo with a spinner appears and after few seconds the spinner stops spinning. After that it is completely stuck and nothing works, I tried pressing Esc and Ctrl+Alt+F3 but nothing works. I have to force shutdown the machine by pressing the power button. When restarted, it most probably boots just fine.
I checked logs but found nothing suspicious there.
It is annoying and also I'm concerned about my data. Please give me pointers to troubleshoot and hopefully resolve it.

"also I'm concerned about my data.". So you have bought an external backup drive and installed a backup utility and run it (which you should do anyway), right ? (-;? Edit your Question to show which log files you have looked at. Did you examine output from dmsg?

Boot without quiet rhgb, when it gets stuck, make a picture, upload it here.

@shellter I looked in system log in GNOME logs app which I guess shows similar output as journalctl do.
@ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, I'm doing so but after posting here, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem again for single time. I'll post once this occurs again.
